# Using Emacs and Gdb to set breakpoints, Why tip is always "Current buffer has no process"?

Tags: emacs, process, gdb

I used Emacs and Gdb to debug my programe, when i set a breakpoint (M-X gud-break) in my programe,then tip is  "Current buffer has no process".
Does anyone have faced this one?

Answer (score 0):

You need start GDB process first...

If you still have error you MUST file bug by: **M-x emacs-bug** and write full steps to reproduce bug.